# Is it possible to partition by aggregation column with engine AggregatingMergeTree()

Tags: clickhouse

Created a materialized view with the engine = AggregatingMergeTree() when inserted into the 'default'.tbl crashes with an exception.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW default.tbl_view ON CLUSTER test
(
    id_key String,
    uid String,
    dt  Date,
    data_timeStamp AggregateFunction(min, Date) 
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() 
PARTITION BY dt
ORDER BY (id_key , uid) 
AS SELECT id_key as id_key,
        toDate(data_timeStamp) as dt,
      uid as uid,
     minState(toDate(data_timeStamp)) as data_timeStamp
FROM `default`.tbl pe
GROUP BY id_key, uid
```

DB::Exception: Illegal type AggregateFunction(min, Date) of argument of function toDate: while pushing to view default.tbl_view (be181a81-ea4d-4118-9b0d-6fb31b48d93e). (ILLEGAL_TYPE_OF_ARGUMENT)

How can I create a view aggregation data_timeStamp Aggregate Function(min, Date) group by id_key, uid and partition By data_timeStamp ? (Clickhouse partitioning)

I tried to do it using SimpleAggregateFunction.
I created a table with the AggregatingMergeTree engine, then I will insert data into it through the materialized view

```
CREATE TABLE `default`.tbl ON CLUSTER test 
(
    key_id String,
    uid String,
    data_timeStamp AggregateFunction(min, Date),
    dt Date
)
Engine = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY dt
ORDER BY (key_id, uid)


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `default`.tbl_view ON CLUSTER test
TO `default`.tbl
AS SELECT key_id as key_id,
        toDate(data_timeStamp) as dt,
        uid as uid,
     minState(toDate(data_timeStamp)) as data_timeStamp
FROM `default`.tb2 pe
GROUP BY key_id, uid
```

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be partitioned by datetime, but datetime is AggregateFunction

Answer (score 0):

The error message you got:

> DB::Exception: Illegal type AggregateFunction(min, Date) of argument of function toDate: while pushing to view default.tbl_view (be181a81-ea4d-4118-9b0d-6fb31b48d93e). (ILLEGAL_TYPE_OF_ARGUMENT)

Is because your MV query is wrong. You're using `AggregateFunction` in your `FROM` table so you should first merge the results and then use `-State` combinator to push the data to another `AggregateFunction` column. You can use `SimpleAggregateFunction` to create the partitioning key.

```
CREATE TABLE `default`.tbl
(
    id_key String,
    uid String,
    data_timeStamp AggregateFunction(min, Date),
    dt Date
)
Engine = AggregatingMergeTree
PARTITION BY dt
ORDER BY (id_key, uid);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW default.tbl_view
(
    id_key String,
    uid String,
    dt  Date,
    partition SimpleAggregateFunction(min, Date),
    data_timeStamp_ AggregateFunction(min, Date)
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() 
PARTITION BY (dt, partition)
ORDER BY (id_key, uid) 
AS
SELECT id_key, uid, dt, min(partition) as partition, minState(data_timeStamp_) as data_timeStamp_ 
FROM (SELECT id_key,
        toDate(minMerge(data_timeStamp)) as dt,
      uid as uid,
     minMerge(data_timeStamp)::date partition,
     minMerge(data_timeStamp)::date as data_timeStamp_
FROM `default`.tbl pe
GROUP BY id_key, uid
)  GROUP BY id_key, uid, dt;


INSERT INTO default.tbl SELECT
    CAST(number, 'String'),
    '1',
    minState(CAST(now(), 'date') - number),
    CAST(now(), 'date') - number
FROM numbers(5)
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    4

OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl_view FINAL;
```

Comment: Your insertion example aggregates by forth column, it does not need to be aggregated according to the logic of my task. it's problem